# How to use prefix with Predis?

Tags: php, redis, predis

I'm using [nrk/predis](https://github.com/nrk/predis) for handling Redis client in my PHP script.

I'm trying to set a prefix to all keys used in this client:

```
$client = new Predis\Client([
    'scheme'    => 'tcp',
    'host'      => REDIS_IP,
    'port'      => REDIS_PORT,
    'password'  => REDIS_PASS,
    'database'  => REDIS_DB,
    'prefix'    => REDIS_PREFIX
]);
```

And it this should work as it stated in their [client configuration](https://github.com/nrk/predis/tree/v1.0#client-configuration).

But `$client->exists("mykey")` returns false, and `$client->exists(REDIS_PREFIX . "mykey")` returns true.

Of course, my goal is to use only `$client->exists("mykey")`.

I checked on the terminal and the key looks ok. (I've inserted the entries manually)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Place the `prefix` option in a new array as the second argument to your connection function. My guess is (after looking at the documentation you linked) that `prefix` does not belong in the first set of connection arguments for `new Predis\Client()` but in the second argument for (the `options` parameter).

Change the code to this:

```
$client = new Predis\Client([
    'scheme'    => 'tcp',
    'host'      => REDIS_IP,
    'port'      => REDIS_PORT,
    'password'  => REDIS_PASS,
    'database'  => REDIS_DB
], [
    'prefix'    => REDIS_PREFIX
]);
```

This should allow you to call `$client->exists('mykey');` and it will use your prefix given in REDIS_PREFIX

Comment: Thank you! didn't notice that. Dumb mistake